# Understanding Dirac Delta

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I found this:
[image: diract]

here: http://www.nada.kth.se/~annak/diracdelta.pdf on page 2

Can anyone explain how and why all the terms are cancelled in the second step?

Comment: The term to be evaluated at $\infty$ and $-\infty$ goes away because $f$ vanishes at $\infty$. The next term becomes $-\int_0^\infty$ becahse $H(x) = 0$ for $x<0$.

Comment: all valid test functions vanish very vast at $\pm \infty$. to be precise, usually they are member of the Schwartz class $\mathcal{S}$. Check out wikipedia for  ore details!

Answer (score 5):

Warning: This argument is both flawed and dangerous. It may give "intuition" but the steps are FORMAL, and are not meaningful.

What the author wants you to think is that $f(\infty)H(\infty)- f(-\infty)H(-\infty) = 0\cdot 1 - f(-\infty)\cdot 0 = 0-0 = 0$ and $H=0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ so the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ can be replaced by an integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

The problem with this argument is that the diract delta "function" is not a function. There is no real (or extended real) function that has the properties that the delta "function" exhibits. What we are hiding here is that we are not integrating in the usual way, we are actually integrating with respect to a diract delta *measure*. The integration by parts formula does not hold in general and it is pure dumb luck that pushing symbols around in this way gives the right answer. Be very careful and take what the author says with great caution.

Comment: Thank you. 1) What do you mean by "integration by parts formula does not hold in general"? 2) Should this just be taken as a sort of definition then?

Comment: i think @nullUser means that one really have to learn distribution theory to really understand this kind of manipulations